Calculate torque on nodes of a branching tree-like structure
Im modelling tree growth and I need to know if a particular tree structure is physically viable, meaning no branches would break at their connection point under their own weight.
My tree representation is similar to these:

where each branch has the same length and weight, and multiple branches can attach to a single node with an arbitrary angle.
It seems to me that to figure out if any of the branches would break, I should calculate the torque applied by each branch on the point it connects to its parent branch and then compare it to a threshold representing the maximum tension supported by the material.
However I am having trouble figuring out how to do that efficiently, because to calculate the torque on a node N, lets say the root, I need to somehow integrate the weight of all the branches that it leads up to.
What I came up with is an algorithm that iterates the tree nodes and calculates the torque for each branch of the node as:
$$t = m \times \frac{d}{2} \times \cos(a)$$
where $m$ is the mass of the branch (summed over all of its sub-branches recursively), $a$ is the angle at which the branch connects to its parent relative to the ground, and $d$ is the horizontal component of the distance between the node position and the center of mass of all branches leading up to the node, calculated as:
$$ d = \lvert \frac{c_b m_b + c_u m_u}{m_b + m_u} - n \rvert $$
where n is the horizontal position of the node the branch attaches to, $c_b$ and $m_b$ are respectively the center of mass and mass of this specific branch segment and $c_u$ and $m_u$ are respectively the center of mass and mass of all branches upstream of the current branch, recursively calculated in the same manner.
In summary, I am recursively calculating the centers of mass and using that to calculate torque individually at each node.
Is this a reasonable approach? Is there a way to calculate and directly propagate torque recursively instead of the centers of mass and mass?

No, I don't think there is another way. You can use graphing software to express the centre of mass as coordinates of that branch and find the centre of mass.
